# Visualizing Crystal Structures

Tags: crystallography

I would like to know if there are any free alternatives to VESTA for visualizing crystal structures.

Thanks

Comment: https://jp-minerals.org/vesta/en/download.html This software is distributed free of charge for academic, scientific, educational, and noncommercial users. Users belonging to commercial enterprises may also use this software at no cost until a license for business users is established. [...] How much more free does it have to be?

Comment: Please, take a look at both answers given [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/4933/24).

Comment: Also this [thread](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/467/what-are-the-freely-available-crystal-structure-visualization-softwares/468#468)